# Merge free space into mounted partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount, gparted

I installed Ubuntu alongside with Linux Mint and removed Linux Mint after in a very dirty way - formatted its partition.
Now I'm stuck with lots of free space that I can not distribute.

Can anyone forward me in the right direction to solve this? I need to merge all of my free space into an Ubuntu partition and get rid of partition nesting (`sda2`/`sda5`) so I have only one partition.

[image: My partition situation]

Comment: You can try to run `resize2fs /dev/sda5`. If it does not work, you need to change the size from a live usb.

Comment: It would be far simpler (and, in my opinion, more useful) to use this as a separate partition instead of merging into one. Would you be open to such an approach?

Comment: @terdon what? no! completely opinion-based. plus if we're doing opinions I personally prefer the resizing option.

Comment: @tatsu well, it's an opinion I can easily defend with facts (using this for `/home`, for example, would let you change OS or reinstall easily, share the partition, protect yourself since a failure in one partition won't affect the rest, make partition block operations faster since it's a smaller partition etc.), but yes, it's an opinion. That's why it was a comment and that's why I said "In my _opinion_".

Comment: I know but this is what advanced users do. managing `/home`'s vs. `/`'s size + automounting + reusing that `/home` in that fatefull OS reinstall is it's own set of challenges he doesn't need to necessarily deal with. it's great, no better, when you're experienced, but otherwise the single partition aproach is more akin to new users. they would be familiar with (for example) taking photos and films onto an extrenal hard disk before reinstalling but less so with mountpoints.

Comment: @terdon the main problem with a separate  /home here is that the user would be left with their original 156G Ubuntu partition, which is only ~40% used... it's a waste of space on small HDD's.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

Using the USB Live CD you used for install (or if you reformatted it since, please remake it using ubuntu's own builtin USB installer creator) boot to the "try ubuntu" menu option, open up gparted.

Right click on "extended" (/dev/sda2) and select "resize/move". Then click and drag the leftmost edge towards the left until all the grey is covered. Then click the big "resize/move" button.

click the green check-mark.

repeat the operation for "ext4" (/dev/sda5).

voila :) !

Comment: You might want to mention that this can only be done if the partition is unmounted so, since this is `/`, it can only be done from another operating system, or a live CD, or from a rescue shell. It's also a good idea to make a backup of your data first, since these operations can be dangerous (although I have done this many times with no problem).

Comment: Also, `sda5` is a logical partition within the `sda2` extended partition. Are you sure it can be expanded? Wouldn't you need to expand `sda2` first, adding the unallocated space to it and then expand `sda5` into that?

Comment: correct on both points.  (on the second point I'm not sure, but let's stick to what is certain to work, so you're right). I edited:  I'm not sure I was entirely correct, feel free to re-edit me.

Comment: The user wanted to get rid of the extended partition.

Answer (score 0):

**Be safe.**

Boot into live USB/DVD

- Since you have no efi partition I assume you have installed Ubuntu in bios mode.
- Backup your data.
- Create a new partition in the free space, should be sda1, check it in gparted.
- Copy partition sda5 to sda1. Command:

  ```
  dd if=/dev/sda5 of=/dev/sda1
  ```
- Change the UUID of sda5 in gparted. Reboot.
- It should reboot in sda1.
- If not.

**Install grub from live USB/DVD.** Using the following commands.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys; do sudo mount --bind $i /mnt$i; done && sudo chroot /mnt
update-grub
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
exit && for i in /sys /proc /dev/pts /dev; do sudo umount /mnt$i; done && sudo umount -l /mnt
```

Reboot You may have two options boot into the first one.
If all is well. Delete the extended partition.
Now you can extend the sda1 in live USB/DVD using gparted.

[FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/#adjusting) can simplify the process.

Comment: Can't have two partitions with the same UUID.

Comment: Right . But I have already told to change the UUID of sda5.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd give detailed instructions on how to resize/move your Ubuntu partition, but in this case, I'd recommend this... as the long term results will be better...

- backup your ~30G+ data to a USB flash key
- lay down a fresh MBR partition table (this will wipe the disk)
- reinstall Ubuntu from scratch
- restore your data from flash key